# Combine files of same name, but in different directories, in numerically ascending order

Tags: linux

I need to combine files (of same name) present in different directories (like traj_1/ traj_2/ etc.) to a single file, but as per the numerically ascending order of the directories.

Attempts like:

cat $(find ./ -name "/homes/epsilon/users/diem/project_tau43_Ab42/tau43_monomer/traj_*/production/3D-RISM/thm_decomposition/thma_vs_time/xmu_data/xmu_res_001_vs_time.dat" | sort -V) > diem/alltraj_Gsolv_res1.dat

cat $(find ./ -wholename /homes/epsilon/users/diem/project_tau43_Ab42/tau43_monomer/traj_*/production/3D-RISM/thm_decomposition/thma_vs_time/xmu_data/xmu_res_001_vs_time.dat" | sort -V) > diem/alltraj_Gsolv_res1.dat

are not working out

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*new.txt" | awk -F/ '{ fil[$NF]+=1;fil1[$NF][$0]="" } END { for (i in fil) { if ( fil[i] > 1) { for (j in fil1[i]) { printf "%s ",j }  printf "\n" } } }'
```

The above script will show all files with the same name in the directory structure displayed on single lines for each entry. Piping the output through to xargs and cat will then print a merged version of the files:

```
find . -name "*new.txt" | awk -F/ '{ fil[$NF]+=1;fil1[$NF][$0]="" } END { for (i in fil) { if ( fil[i] > 1) { for (j in fil1[i]) { printf "%s ",j }  printf "\n" } } }' | xargs cat
```

Explanation:

```
find . -name "*new.txt" | awk -F/ 
'    { 
        fil[$NF]+=1; # Take the file name and create an array with an incrementing 
                       value for each file name observed.
        fil1[$NF][$0]="" # Create a 2 dimentional array with the file name as the 
                           first index and the full path as the second
     } 
 END { 
        for (i in fil) { # Loop through the entries in the fil array
           if ( fil[i] > 1) { # If there is more than one entry (entries with the same 
                                file name) process.
               for (j in fil1[i]) { 
                 printf "%s ",j # Print the full path
               }  
               printf "\n" 
           } 
         } 
      }'
```